# Read all records from the database using call functions in ims

Tags: database, cobol, dbd, ims

I want to write a batch program with IMS that can get all the records in the database. The structure of my database is as follows: a root segment and a segment below it that has several occurrences and another segment under the second segment that also has several occurrences.
How can I do this? So that the least call function is used?

Comment: [Coding a batch (IMS) program in COBOL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ims/13.1.0?topic=SSEPH2_13.1.0/com.ibm.ims13.doc.apg/ims_codingbatchcobol.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GN call (Get Next) to traverse through an entire database sequentially. You may issue GN calls until you receive a GB status code back which means essentially means "end of database".

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ims/15.1.0?topic=management-gnghn-call